# Event/information pass from servlet to ZK Mvvm

Tags: java, servlets, mvvm, zk, zkoss

How to forward an event/information from java servlet controller to ZK MVVM model. Basically, i have some informations into servlet layer but based on data, i need to process into ZK UI layer. I couldn't use ZK event queues/Global commasnd as it requires current exections. Also, i don't have any third event queue system.

Posting an event/request from servlet and recieve into ZK MVVM layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need to share data, then you can store the data in a session attribute and get it from ZK ViewModel. (see [https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer's%20Reference/Integration/Accessing%20Java%20EE%20Scope%20Objects](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK%20Developer%27s%20Reference/Integration/Accessing%20Java%20EE%20Scope%20Objects))

If you need to actively send an event to notify ZK ViewModel, then you need to  use [session-scope event queue](https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZK_Developer%27s_Reference/Event_Handling/Event_Queues#The_Scope_of_an_Event_Queue). Only desktop event queue requires an `Execution`.

Since a HttpServlet cannot access a desktop, you cannot send an event via a desktop-scope event queue.